# Which Python versions do I need to support as the upstream author of a Python library for Debian?

Tags: python, debian

I'm the upstream- and Debian maintainer of a [Python library](https://github.com/venthur/python-debianbts) which is installed as a dependency of a `required` package in the Debian ecosystem, so this library is pretty much installed on every Debian system. I'm trying to support older Python versions as long as possible and my rule of thumb for this package is to support versions down to whatever is currently in Debian/stable. However, there is also Debian/oldstable (even /oldoldstable) and I wonder if there are some guidelines that help to make the decision which Python versions can be dropped which should be supported still?

The most relevant documentation for the issue is probably the [Debian Python Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/index.html), but I'm unable to find the information here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Debian is concerned, the package you publish should support the currently supported Python versions. So if you published a package when `oldstable` was still `stable`, the package you published then should have supported the `oldstable` Python versions. When you publish something now, the current `stable` is your target.

But going back in time, there is no particular reason for an `oldstable` user to be disappointed if some current packages are not usable on their platform; the decision to use an old system is usually motivated by a desire to maintain it for a longer time, not make it do new things which were not possible at the time it was configured.

Of course, there are situations where you *want* to support older systems. If you publish a tool for forensic analysis of hacked systems, you really want to be able to run that on older versions, too; but this is dictated by other factors then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm struggling to find the "currently supported Python versions". Are you saying I only need to support whatever is in current stable? That has been my rule of thumb until now anyways, but is that written down somewhere?

Comment: As of right now, `apt-get install python3` on Bullseye will pull in 3.9. https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3-defaults shows which versions are in which releases; so right now `oldstable` had 3.7 and `oldoldstable` had 3.5.

Comment: A separate discussion is if you still want to support Python 2, but that should mean 2.7 in practice anyhow. https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-defaults ... Now that's stability for ya.